# When moving Camera a keyframe is set on every object

Tags: animation, camera, keyframes

I made my second animation and wanted to animate the camera. I added an empty object that the camera can track.

When I move the camera to point a (set a keyframe) and move it to point B (set a keyframe) every object in the scene has those two keyframes now. Every light, the empty object, the plane, my 3 characters, everything. And when I decide to move the second camera keyframe, every object get another keyframe.

After 3 minutes of work every object has 2000 keyframes but i just want the keyframes only on the camera.

Same goes for the camera. I change a light, camera has new keyframes.

i am able to deactivate the objects as example the light in the dope sheet so they do not get new keyframes from the camera. but this is an annoying fix of the problem.

i tried to make a new action but it does not work.

how can i fix this problem without locking every object every time to make sure that only one of my selected objects get the keyframes?

Comment: Maybe you have assigned the same action to all these objects by accident, not sure how to remove an action from several objects at once though... maybe in the Dope Sheet in Action Editor mode, select the camera, duplicate the action for the camera and delete the original action?

Comment: Hi ToTheGodds...unfortunately you didn't give us any useful technical information what you have done. Assuming your are a beginner and to get a quick answer i recommend providing your blend file so we can check it out. thx.